# Bio_free not closing connection

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have developed a ssl client using the code shown in this website

```
http://www.chesterproductions.net.nz/blogs/it/c/an-ssl-client-using-openssl/245/
```

But after calling `r = BIO_free(bio);` the connection still does not get closed. Only after closing my client application does the connection close.
I am verifying this using `CurrPorts` software, which shows which all ports are in connected state.

I have tried `BIO_ssl_shutdown(bio);` but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the fault. It was the server not clearing its FD_SET which was creating an issue. Though I am not sure why it happened so :(